# Proving an equation has exactly one solution over a given interval.

Tags: calculus

The equation $e^{-87x}+96\textrm{cos}(87x)=0$ has exactly one solution over the closed interval $[0,\pi/87]$. This function is continuous (I think) so I can use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

So I find $f(0)$ and $f(\pi/87)$ which equal $97$ and $-95.9568...$ respectively, so since the interval has positive and negative values, which means that the function passes through $0$ at some moment.

But I'm having some trouble finding that value, and how to prove there are no other solutions.


Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For the record, you have not been asked to find the zeros of that function in the interval. You have been asked to prove that there is exactly one. So you not being able to find zeros is not an issue.

Comment: Okay, so how do I prove that there is only one solution?

Comment: Try monotone in the interval

Answer (score 1):

First hint: solve $e^{-x}+96\cos x=0$ and show it has a unique solution over $[0,\pi]$, which is equivalent to your problem with the substitution $x\mapsto 87x$.

Second hint: consider $f(x)=e^{-x}+96\cos x$. You already observed that $f(0)=97>0$ and $f(\pi)=e^{-\pi}-96<0$, because $0<e^{-\pi}<1$. You can see that $f'(x)=-e^{-x}-96\sin x$ and so…